# How can I enable individual bone xray instead of full armature xray?

Tags: python, rigging, 3d-view, armature, bones

is it possible to somehow make bones have individual x-ray / in front properties? I understand that this property is being held in it's parent data block for the Armature object but why can't it also be done for children elements? would it be kind of the same way how you can't really make individual faces in front in edit mode but you can with shaders?

or is it just a drawing limitation on Blender's viewport? could it be somehow be implemented with code?

imgur clip:

[per bone xray](https://imgur.com/a/q2Ciket)